# AC voltage measurement using non-linear opto-couplers

Tags: voltage-measurement

Trying to build a cheap voltage measurement circuit without any neutral, that is,  line-to-line (415V @50hz) isolated voltage measurement.

I found the AMC3330 galvanically isolated op-amp which does the job but it is expensive, and not looking for this solutions.

Any suggestion on other line-line voltage measurement circuit?

Comment: You might be interested in this site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for the heads up, looking for a circuit recommendation, not a product shared above documentation for reference, have recived simple voltage divider network with isolated op amp as an answer, which is not the solution I am looking at.

Comment: The trouble is that asking for circuit recommendations is also basically asking for (or soliciting) opinions: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers*. The only way around this is a complete specification of what you want so it leads unambiguously to one definite answer/method.

Comment: @Andyaka i understand the point, and I was hoping someone could point me to a correct direction, i got a recommendation on make a virtual ground and then measuring it. Still figuring it out.